# C++ error: cannot be used as a function, some stray error

Tags: c++

I have write a calendar code, but I have some stray error.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int month, year, Y, M;
    int day[13] = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    int FirstDayofMonth;

    cout << "please enter year!" << endl;
    cin >> year;
    while(year < 1600)
    {
        cout << "please do not enter year less than 1600!" << endl;
        cin >> year;
    }
    cout << "please enter month! (1~12)" << endl;
    cin >> month;
    Y = year – (14 – month)/12;
    M = month + 12 * ((14 - month) / 12) - 2;
    FirstDayofMonth = (Y + Y/4 - Y/100 + Y/400 + 31*M/12 + 1)%7;
}
```

The other part is to print the result.
And it shows me the error below:

```
try.cpp:18: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
try.cpp:18: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
try.cpp:18: error: stray ‘\223’ in program
try.cpp:18: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
try.cpp:18: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
try.cpp:18: error: stray ‘\223’ in program
try.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
try.cpp:18: error: expected `)' before ‘month’
try.cpp:18: error: ‘year’ cannot be used as a function
```

18:     `Y = year – (14 – month)/12;`

I don't know what the error means. How can I fix it?

Comment: Weird characters instead of spaces?

Comment: something is missing after the 2nd "-" in line 18.

Comment: Look at `(14 – )month)` again...

Comment: Sorry, I paste the wrong code, I have edited it now, but still have some error

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is reporting bytes `\342`, `\200`, and `\223` (represented in octal) in your code. These bytes make up the UTF-8 encoding of [EN DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). This is a character used in ranges (e.g. June–August) or relationships (e.g. Sydney–Los Angeles flight) in English text. The minus character typically accepted by C++ compilers is the ASCII compatible [HYPHEN-MINUS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm), which is the character available on a QWERTY keyboard.

Looks like you've copy and pasted this code from somewhere and have the wrong character for subtraction in this line:

```
Y = year – (14 – )month)/12;
```

Also note the extra parenthesis that shouldn't be there. Perhaps you want:

```
Y = year - (14 - month) / 12;
```

Comment: This won't compile either, you need an operator after the `)`.

Comment: @ysap Just mentioned that.

Comment: ok, I know the question. I paste the wrong "-"... thank you very much!!!!

Comment: @JackHou - Just curious - how did you get that dash into the code in the first place?

Comment: @ysap I refer from my teacher's file and copy from it. maybe our teacher uncarefully use wrong dash

Comment: @ysap: It might [have been a PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67179052/).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have an extra `)` after the 2nd `-` in that line:

```
Y = year – (14 – )month)/12;
```

should be:

```
Y = year – (14 – month)/12;
```

Comment: That was changed in revision 3. Related: *[Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)*